# Change variable values through getter Typescript Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm trying to change the value in a Variable if the recieved content from a Json is empty. My approach is it to alter my getter Method. For some reasons it seems like the getter Method doesn't get called and it changes nothing, even though I make a call on it. Maybe you Guys can help me.

Here I try to customise my getter, but at runtime it doesn't get used:

```
export class Chart {
   private _options: any;

   get options(): any {
     if (this._options){
        this._options = {rotation: Math.PI, circumference: Math.PI};
        return this._options;
     } else {
        console.log(this._options);
        return this._options;
     }
   }
}
```

And here is my component.ts class where I try to use this Variable:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Chart} from "../main-content/entity/dashboard-config-fetcher";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  chart: Chart;

  public options: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = this.chart.options;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: add parenthesis on your method. this.options = this.chart.options();

Comment: Are you sure that the chart value passed in your component is an actual instance of the Chart class ?

Comment: I tried this already and sadly I get this Error: `ERROR TypeError: this.chart.options is not a function`

Comment: @David I checked with: `console.log(this.chart instanceof Chart)` and got a **false**, so it seems thats the problem. Do I have to change my `@Input` Annotation? I dont really understand why its not an instance of it.

Comment: you have to check the callchain and figure out how that chart value is created

Comment: sry for the late response this was exactly the Problem. Thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly I think ur missing a !

```
if (this._options) --> if(!this.options)
```

Otherwise you will return undefined if there is nothing stored in the ***_options*** variable

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response but sadly I don't even come so far, to test the if statement, because the getter doesn't get used.